# Eclipse(IBM RAD 7.5.3): "class cannot be resovled to a type" error

Tags: java, eclipse

I am having a problem with my eclipse workspace that is unable to resolve classes in EAR library jar files. I had same problems before, and cleaning and re-building the project solved the issue, but that doesn't work anymore, and I find this quite strange. I went far as deleting projects from my workspace, and re-importing them, but that didn't fix the issue either. I found a blog entry on a similar issue:

http://philip.yurchuk.com/2008/12/03/eclipse-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-error/

I tried the solutions suggested on the site, but they too failed to resolve my issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally such issues occur due to fundamental issues in your Build Path such as a missing JRE or a new install of one. Show us what are the main problems by doing the below steps:

1. Open the Problems view.
2. Click on the little triangle and select Preferences. Here, set the number of visible items to something more than 100. I keep it as 1000 or more usually.

   [image]
3. Click on Configure Contents on the same context menu and select "On selected element and its children". Make sure the All Errors option is checked.

   [image]

Once you do the above, you will be able to isolate the issue by just clicking on the problematic project. The Problems view shows all the errors with the project which are preventing you from building it. Usually, this error will be due to a Build Path conflict.

Meanwhile, if nothing works, just create a new workspace and start afresh.